# UITableViewController inside a UIViewController with swift and Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, swift3

I have a problem similar to this: 
[UITableViewController inside a UIViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20523874/uitableviewcontroller-inside-a-uiviewcontroller)

I follow exactly the same steps.
I have a `UIViewController` with my custom class: `MyCustomClassViewController` and `UITableViewController` named `MyCustomUITableViewController`.

Inside of my ViewController I added a `Container View` and drag and drop to my `UITableView` and selected `embed`.

Ok, now, when I executed the project, I got this error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'containerView is
>   required.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view controller classes are incorrectly constructed. Look at your embed segue, and make sure that:

- The source view controller is marked in the identity inspector as MyCustomClassViewController
- The destination view controller is marked in the identity inspector as MyCustomUITableViewController

Also go back to your code and make sure also that you have the correct inheritance:

- MyCustomClassViewController should be a UIViewController subclass
- MyCustomUITableViewController should a UITableViewController subclass

You might even have to delete the segue, and even the view controllers, from the storyboard, and recreate them along with the container view and the embed segue.