# TableViewController embedded in ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

Following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25193002/4805995), I embedded a TableViewController into a container of a ViewController like this:

[image]

Now that I've got two ViewControllers (one embedded in another); should I create a .swift file (class) for each ViewController, or just one which controls both using some kind of hierarchy? I also read some answers about delegate and dataSource but applied in cases that weren't exactly like this one.

Comment: How you organize your classes within files is entirely up to you. You can have both in one swift file if you want, or have them separate. Different people will have different opinions. If you are asking because there is some problem you are trying to solve, then you don't give any indication what that might be.

Comment: This might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20523874/uitableviewcontroller-inside-a-uiviewcontroller

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with both the approaches,
I would recommend making two files separately for both controllers.

Either way you have to create two classes. So files wont matter.