# Unrecognized Selector / Connecting view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to load a nib file to a UITableView, which i've placed inside a UIView using storyboards.

The UITableView and UIView have two separate ViewControllers and i'm trying to connect them, but i'm getting an error message saying unrecognized selector. What does this mean?

Thank you!

VC1

```
class CreateMeetPlanning: CreateMeet {

@IBOutlet var tableView: TableViewPlanning!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    }

@IBAction func closePlanning(_ sender: UIButton) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

//Automatically open keyboard
//override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    //super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    //planningRow.becomeFirstResponder()
//}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

}
```

VC2

```
class TableViewPlanning: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

// forcing status bar to hide
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}

// properties
var todo: Array<String> = [""]
var defTodo: Array<String> = [""]


// selecting textfield in first empty row

func responder() {
    self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .none, animated: false)
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)) as? TableViewCell {
        cell.textField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}


// saving data to UserDefaults
func save() {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    defaults.set(self.todo, forKey: "todo")
}

// retrieving data from UserDefaults
func get() {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    self.todo = defaults.stringArray(forKey: "todo") ?? [""]
    tableView.reloadData()
}


// action on tapping "Done" on a keyboard

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    let task = textField.text ?? " "
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForView(textField)
    if indexPath?.row == 0 {
        self.todo.insert(task, at: 1)
        print(self.todo)
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .top)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
    else {
        self.todo[indexPath!.row] = task
        tableView.reloadData()

    }
    responder()
    save()
    return true
}

// TABLEVIEW methods
// amount of rows
public override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.todo.count
}

// content for the row
public override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableViewCell
    cell.textField.delegate = self
    cell.textField.text = self.todo[indexPath.row].description
    // cell.textField.becomeFirstResponder()
    return cell
}

// deleting rows: all rows to be deleted if first row is deleted, others as usual.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    if indexPath.row != 0 {
        if editingStyle == .delete
        {
            self.todo.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            tableView.endUpdates()
        }
    }
    else { if editingStyle == .delete
    {
        self.todo = self.defTodo
        tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    print(self.todo)
    responder()

    save()
}

@objc func refresh(refresh: UIRefreshControl) {
    refresh.endRefreshing()
    responder()
}

// ViewController life-cycle
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    get()
    refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl?.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "")
    refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refresh(refresh:)), for: .valueChanged)
    refreshControl?.tintColor = UIColor.red
    tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl
    responder()
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
}
}
```

ERROR

```
2017-11-21 17:48:15.599430+0100 meetIOS[416:43942] [MC] Lazy loading NSBundle MobileCoreServices.framework
2017-11-21 17:48:15.601629+0100 meetIOS[416:43942] [MC] Loaded MobileCoreServices.framework
2017-11-21 17:48:15.631201+0100 meetIOS[416:43942] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2017-11-21 17:48:15.797665+0100 meetIOS[416:43942] refreshPreferences: HangTracerEnabled: 0
2017-11-21 17:48:15.797774+0100 meetIOS[416:43942] refreshPreferences: HangTracerDuration: 500
2017-11-21 17:48:15.797820+0100 meetIOS[416:43942] refreshPreferences: ActivationLoggingEnabled: 0 ActivationLoggingTaskedOffByDA:0
2017-11-21 17:48:17.744420+0100 meetIOS[416:43942] -[meetIOS.TableViewPlanning superview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x101d1a9f0
2017-11-21 17:48:17.746086+0100 meetIOS[416:43942] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[meetIOS.TableViewPlanning superview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x101d1a9f0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x182bd5d04 0x181e24528 0x182be31c8 0x18c3cb110 0x182bdb6b0 0x182ac101c 0x18c014074 0x18c2dc5ec 0x18c747160 0x18c7472d8 0x18c746e98 0x18c2dc57c 0x18c747160 0x18c746e98 0x18c59c0cc 0x18c747160 0x18c7472d8 0x18c746e98 0x18c59b40c 0x18c37b17c 0x18c12aee4 0x18c00cba4 0x18c00cad4 0x18c38ac04 0x18c383a2c 0x18c385428 0x18c387ccc 0x18c388200 0x18c387c1c 0x18c0ebaa8 0x18c910038 0x18c92ab30 0x18c92a9d4 0x18c92aca8 0x18c041608 0x18c041588 0x18c02c2f0 0x18c040e7c 0x18c04099c 0x18c03be6c 0x18c00d378 0x18c95a85c 0x18c95cde8 0x18c955d04 0x182b7e2e8 0x182b7e268 0x182b7daf0 0x182b7b6c8 0x182a9bfb8 0x184933f84 0x18c0702e8 0x100948e14 0x1825be56c)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Please just post relevant code. And clearly point out the exact line of code causing the error.

Comment: Why did you remove all of the code? I meant that you should post just relevant code and point out the line of code actually causing your error.

Comment: New to stackoverflow, just getting the hang of the rules here, sorry! But that's the thing, i'm not quite sure what the issue is here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue most probably is in the storyboard where you have `CreateMeetPlanning` VC, you have a tableView which you have assigned to the outlet `tableView: TableViewPlanning!`. But `TableViewPlanning` is not a UITableView but its a `UITableViewController`. Hence the crash.

You need to use container view in storybard to embed UITabelviewcontroller and then change its class to `TableViewPlanning`, before connecting it to the outlet. Something similar has been done in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20523874/uitableviewcontroller-inside-a-uiviewcontroller).

Comment: Thank you, will try it out!

Comment: Glad to help. Cheers!!